# Resolving internal domains stops randomly while local DNS can still be pinged

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-manager, dns

Our local network has internal domains that end on `.int`. When running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS as guest in VirtualBox running on a Windows 10 host, it randomly looses the ability to resolve those domains.

When this happens, neither ping nor a browser are able to reach a server through an internal `.int` domain, but by querying the IP. Only restarting the virtual machine enables the resolving of `.int` domains again. External domains that end on a regular top-level domain can be resolved at all times.

So far, I have tried the following steps:

- `sudo service network-manager restart`
- disconnect and reconnect the virtual cable connection to the virtual machine
- `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches`
- resolve one of our `.int` domains using nslookup with `--dns-ip=` to force using our internal DNS server for resolving

All of this did not lead to an internal `.int` domain being resolved. Only rebooting the Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox allows to resolve the internal domains again.

While resolving of internal domains is broken, `nmcli device show [device]` shows that the internal DNS server is still listed as `IP4.DNS[1]` and responds to a ping.

Any hints on how to further examine and solve this problem would be appreciated.